# EAR application deployment on Wildfly 22 fails to find javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: wildfly, classloader

I'm trying to deploy an EAR application to WildFly Preview 22.0.1.Final. I'm aware that JBoss/WildFly class loading is different from e.g. WAS, so I went through docs but I'm still not sure if I understand everything.

When deploying EAR, I'm getting the following error(s):

```
13:43:14,771 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean in Module "deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean (Module "deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): javax.servlet.Filter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
```

EAR package has multiple libraries under `lib` folder and some of them are Spring jars. Apparently every use of class that uses some `javax.*` class causes error (warn to be exact) and the whole deployment fails. I'm guessing that `javax.*` classes are simply invisible to my EAR but I just can't make it work.

I've tried to add some path reference (see below) but deployment still fails.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others
        classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="lib/log4j/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/log4j/log4j-core-2.20.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/slf4j/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.20.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/log4j/log4j-web-2.20.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/slf4j/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-instrument-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/aopalliance/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-beans-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-aop-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-tx-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-core-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-aspects-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-jdbc-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-expression-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-web-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-context-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/spring/spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/apache/commons-lang3-3.13.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/google/gson-2.7.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/joda/joda-time-2.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lib/example/Utils-0.0.4.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I've decided to deploy my app on WildFly 29.0.0.Final. Of course I've used `jakarta.*` classes and Spring libs compatible with Jakarta EE 10. It seems that `Filter` class is not a problem anymore, but I'm getting the following error:

```
12:33:03,150 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.example.sample.ejb.SampleBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndexUtil.findMethod(ClassReflectionIndexUtil.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@29.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.handleStatelessSessionBean(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@29.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.deploy(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3297)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2371)
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server@21.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module "deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:200)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 17 more

12:33:03,154 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.example.sample.ejb.SampleBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService]"]
}
12:33:03,155 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.example.sample.ejb.SampleBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService]"]
}
12:33:03,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.example.sample.ejb.SampleBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module \"deployment.SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SampleWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"SampleEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService]"]
}
```

Spring libraries are in `<ear_module>/lib/spring` folder and spring-context (containing `ApplicationContext` class) is one of them. Why is `NoClassDefFoundError` still appearing?

Comment: Why are you excluding the servlet API path?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm sorry for a late response. What do you mean by 'excluding the servlet API path'? Based on [this](https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-deploy/practical-examples-of-jboss-deployment-structure-xml/) article `export="true"` includes module in classpath, or am I wrong?

Comment: My apologies, I read it wrong. Really you shouldn't need that `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` at all. Are you including the servlet-api.jar and other Jakarta EE API JAR's in your deployment?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes, servlet (and ejb, mail, jaxws,...) api jar is in my EAR along with other libraries. Is that ok? I've read that Wildfly 22 still support Java EE 8, but still, those JEE8 jars should be included in EAR, right? I do not use Jakarta (jakarta.*) classes in my app.

Comment: No, you do not want to include the Java EE 8 libraries in your deployment. WildFly already provides those for you. You won't have to use the Jakarta namespace until you migrate to WildFly 27+ and Jakarta EE 10.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I can see that Wildfly 22 does not have old servlet api jar in module folder. I'm guessing a bytecode transformation from  javax.* to jakarta.* is done here? Just trying to understand where Wildfly picks up old servlet api... Anyway, I've removed JEE8 libs from my deployment, but `javax.servlet.Filter` is still not found. Also `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` is not found either, although Spring jars are included in my deployment.

Comment: WildFly 22 is a Jakarta EE 8 container, effectively Java EE 8. The Servlet API module is definitely there. The migration from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` was only done in Wildfly Preview for 22.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm sorry, it looks like I've had Wildfly Preview 22.0.1.Final installed, never thought about that before. Anyway, eventually I'll run my app on Jakarta EE 10 container so I've tried to deploy it on WildFly 29. I've changed all the necessary imports in my code (used `jakarta.*` classes) and now `Filter` class is not a problem anymore. Instead I'm getting `ClassNotFoundError` on Spring classes (see my EDIT). Required Spring jars are defenitely in my EAR package but it looks like class loading is not done properly. Any idea?

Comment: If you want to use Jakarta EE 10 and WildFly 29 you'd need to use Spring 6 as that targets Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm using the latest version (6.0.11) and I'm getting the error above.

Comment: Are you including the Spring libraries in you deployment? The Jakarta EE 10 libraries do not need to be, and really should not be, included in your deployment. However, Spring libraries will need to be included in your deployment or deployed as a module.

Comment: Yes, all Spring libraries are included in my deployment and I've removed Jakarta EE 10 libs also.  Earlier you wrote that `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is not needed in my case. I suspect that I should add classpath entries to WAR's `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: No. Any libraries on your EAR/lib will be added to all deployments in your EAR.

Comment: Well, I've removed `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and `MANIFEST.MF`. I've also clear some Wildfly temp files and now it deploys on Wildfly 29 without any error. Still don't know how to make it work on Wildfly 22 using `javax` classes, but I'll leave that issue for some other time. Thank you very much for all your guidance!